# NSDateFormatter, dateFromString returns nil

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Added this code

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *entry = @"March 28, 2012";       
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];     
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:entry];
```

The date returns nil value. I have doubt about the entry date string.Is it possible to convert this into date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format is wrong. Please do as following.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *entry = @"March 28, 2012";       
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];     
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:entry];
```

**Edit**

```
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"];
```

Comment: Also i need another type of format...NSString *entry = @"March 28, 2012 11:15 AM";

Answer (score 3):

Your date format string and date value string does not match.

Either

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *entry = @"2012-03-28";    //Changed this   
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];   //Kept it as yours  
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:entry];
```

OR

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *entry = @"March 28, 2012";   //Kept is as yours    
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];    //Changed it 
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:entry];
```